# Gaussian Mixture Model 1D data

Tags: matlab, probability, probability-density, mixture-model

I have modeled my 1D data (1000*1 matrix) into 3 Gaussians, using

```
gmdistribution.fit(X,3)
```

How can I plot something Like this?

It shows the probability of a given point belonging to each class.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Write a function `plotGaussian`, which takes the mean, the variance, and a range of values. The function should generate the points to plot, and call the `plot` function.  Then do `hold on`, and call `plotGaussian` 3 times.